# heroku Build succeeded but application error:at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, mern

this is my first time here and I hope you can help me.

I have this app that fully works when I start it from VS Code,

(-$ npm start on the root folder and it starts the back-end and
$npm start on "front-end" folder and it start the react app).

I changed the  structure because I discovered this is the strucure that heroku requires.
ex.:

|app (kasa)
-|fron-tend (react app)
-|middleware
-|models
-|node-modules(backend)
-|routes
-|.env
-|package.json(back-end)
-|server.js
-|gitignore

In my server.js file I'm using dotenv package and the path package
..

I'm using dotenv to store 4 secret environment variables:

-The first one is the mongo db connection:

MONGO_DB_URL=fefokpofk3o...(in server.js I'm using it:
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL))

-The second one is the secret token that I'm using with jsonwebtoken pacakge to authenticate users.

-The third one is NODE_ENV=production

-The last hidden variable is PORT=3000

In my server.js file I have:

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL)

```
.then(() => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
        console.log("CONNECTED TO MONGO DB AND listening on SECRET PORT.")
    })
})
//....
...
__dirname = path.resolve();if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {//app.use(express.static("front-end/build"));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"front-end","build", "index.html"));})
;}else
{app.get("/", (req, res) => {res.send("api running...");});}
```

I put a .gitignore file in the root folder with:

.env

In the package json (backend) I have the script for heroku
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"

In the root folder I have the "Procfile"
Inside the Procfile: "web: node server.js"

Everything run (locally) when I try to test with npm start

I created the Heroku app.

Then when i received the link i changed the proxy address in  package json (frontend) with the link
"proxy": "https://dry-basin-22265.herokuapp.com/",

Then i made npm run build in the folder "front-end" to generate the build folder.

In the packahe json file backend i put

"engines": {
"node": "16.17.1"
},

I pushed everything on git and checked, everything seems ok:

https://github.com/Davide0097/kasa

Then I deployed everything on heroku and it says build succeded.

In eroku settings I put my environment variables there, I put all of them.

The app is crashing and when I do $ heroku logs --tail I receive

```
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217181+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. 
One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217203+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217207+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:413:10
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217210+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217213+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217216+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217216+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1266:10)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217216+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:412:20)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217217+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:60:10)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217217+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217223+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217223+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-8h0hxyd-shard-00-00.rdc3nle.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217224+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-8h0hxyd-shard-00-01.rdc3nle.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217224+00:00 app[web.1]: 'ac-8h0hxyd-shard-00-02.rdc3nle.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217227+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217227+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217227+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217228+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217228+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217228+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: 'atlas-pwu0r5-shard-0',
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217228+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217229+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217229+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: 0,
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217229+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217229+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217229+00:00 app[web.1]: code: undefined
2022-11-21T05:12:39.217230+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-11-21T05:12:40.086339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-11-21T05:12:40.287666+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

-I tried to remove the variable PORT on heroku settings

- I tried to put the .env.development file (HOST=name.herokuapp.com) in the root folder
- I tried to remove the .env folder manually before pushing on heroku.
- I tried to put in my .gitignore(root folder) "build" and "/front-end/build".

Comment: That's just the last few lines from your log. Please run `heroku logs` without `--tail`, then [edit] your question and add all contiguous error and warning lines from the bottom to your question.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response, I edited the answer, I also tried to allow access from all the ip adress on my mongo db atlas.

Comment: You can't just whitelist one IP address. Heroku can use [any IP address from the underlying Amazon infrastructure](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-add-heroku-dynos-to-our-allowlist-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku). Either whitelist that entire range (not great from a security perspective) or use [an add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#network) that provides a static outgoing IP address.